# Where is the ethereum DHT located

Tags: ethereum

What way does the Ethereum protocol, actually allow peers to connect to each other, does it have a DHT somewhere that people use to find peers?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after. https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md